# Reuse build job for many repositories

Tags: gitlab-ci

Say I have a standardised Maven build that I can describe in Gitlab CI.

I would like to reuse this Maven build in 100 repositories.

What is the best way to achieve this with as little code duplication as possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "standardised Maven build"? Do you mean that you want to use the build _artifacts_ of a particular project in many other projects, or you want to reuse the build _job definition_, like a shell script or similar?

Comment: @sytech The job definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reusing job definitions, GitLab CI Templates fill this use case well. There's many ways to [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) a template in your project configuration by using the `include:` keyword. It might look something like this:

```yaml
# your template file
# mytemplate.yml
maven-build:
  variables:
    MY_MAVEN_OPS: "" # variables may be useful for customizing behavior easily 
  stage: build
  script:
    - maven ... # you build this
```

Then in your 100 other projects, you may have something minimal in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` to reuse the above configuration like:

```yaml
include:
  - project: jfabianmeier/templates
    file: mytemplate.yml
    ref: main # or a tag, git SHA, or whatever
```

You can also configure a project to use a [remote CI configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file), so committing a configuration to all projects can be avoided entirely. This setting can be configured with the GitLab API, too. This would certainly be the solution with the absolute minimal amount of repeated code, albeit somewhat inflexible.